# Diffrence beetween Imageview and Imagebutton respect to memory occupy by OS

Tags: android, memory-management

I have recently notice in one of my project that on some layout i define `ImageButton` and on some layout i define `ImageView`.

both are working fine with same role and same task.

**but,**

my question is; is there proper way ? and if not than what is main diffrence beetween tham.
 And also let me know any memory related diffrence for define `imageview` and `imagebutton`?

Which component occupy more memory on running.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageButton` is-a `ImageView` which essentially just supplies a default style for the image button, and the image button default style supplies a button background drawable.

With everything else held constant, changing an `ImageView` without a background to an `ImageButton` consumes more memory since the background takes up some. If you're concerned, use a memory analysis tool to find out whether the difference is significant.

Which one to use: Use `ImageButton` if you want an `ImageView` with button styling. If you just want to display an image, use `ImageView`.

Comment: Having you check answers of Suhail Mehta?

Answer (score 2):

ImageView extends View

where as

ImageButton extends ImageView.

ImageView is used set icons from different sources where as ImageButton ,displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user .

Memory allocation of both the views depends on the image src else there is not significance difference in terms of memory .

Comment: Thanks but your view and laalto view is totlay diffrence and many other person view also. dont know but i not understand properly that

Comment: @LazyCoder: "your view and laalto view is totlay diffrence" -- no, it is not.

Comment: @CommonsWare plz help on this i m so cunfuse right now regarding this

Comment: Ok if you think i am wrong . take a imageView and ImageButton add same src to both ,analyse it using MAT. You will see there is no significant difference. Thats why i used the word "significant" .

Comment: actually i checked it using memory analyser with taking 100 imageview and imagebutton i noticed imagebuttopn occupy more heap size for running

Comment: I was adding an answer but the other two appeared first that are pretty much the same thing I was answering, but it appears that there're some disagreement on the comments so I guess a nice link can settle it, here is the difference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageButton.java

Comment: whats the difference? divide it by 100 and tell

Comment: hint... it's on line 87 `super(context, attrs, defStyle);`